# Cannot add attribute to an element in XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, attributes

I want to add an attribute "driver" to an element "testDetails" in my XML file. I have few elements `testDetails` in the XML and I want to add the attribute to the last one. I created this:

```
Element testDetails;        
NodeList findRootElementList = document.getElementsByTagName("testDetails");
int iterator = findRootElementList.getLength();
Node node = findRootElementList.item(iterator);
testDetails = (Element)node;
testDetails.setAttribute("driver", driver)
```

;

But the variable `testDetails` is `null` at `testDetails.setAttribute("driver", driver);`

But when I previously had this:

```
Element testSuite = null;       
        NodeList findRootElementList = document.getElementsByTagName("testSuite");
        for(int iterator = 0; iterator < findRootElementList.getLength(); iterator++) {
            Node node = findRootElementList.item(iterator);
            if(node.getNodeName().equals("testSuite")) {
                testSuite = (Element)node;
            }
```

this variable (here it is called `testSuite`) was not null, the line `testSuite = (Element)node;` work fine here.

What is the difference here? Why won't it set the `node` to `testDetails`?

Comment: use `findRootElementList.item(iterator-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getLength() - 1` as the index is zero based so the last item in a list of e.g. 5. has index 4.

Answer (score -1):

Last index of list = len(list) - 1 
Because index starting with 0 and length with 1 in case of list.